# Run several procedures after constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working with C# and Entity Framework 5. When I create the model, EF5 generate several classes, for example user's class like

```
public class User{}
```

This class is autogenerated every time that I modify the model then I create another class as a partial like

```
public partial class User{}
```

To add several function, properties or procedures. My problem is that I need run one procedure when the class is instantiated.

I imagine like

```
public class User {
    public User(){
    }
}

public partial class User()
{
    public void OtherProc(){}
}
```

and `OtherProc()` is called automatically when the constructor has finished.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How are you getting the classes to be autogenerated, some of the autogeneration methods allow you to modify the script it follows so you could make the autogenerated code call `OtherProc`. Also is there a specific reason you are using EF 5 instead of EF 6.1?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectmaterialized.aspx) event to execute your code after entity creation. But it will work only when object is loaded from the database. So complete solution should include some kind of business logic layer that handles initialization operations of entities. Here is a snippet:

```
AdventureWorks2012Entities context = new AdventureWorks2012Entities();
((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += (sender, e) => 
{
    //will fire for newly loaded entities
    if (e.Entity is User)
        InitNewUser((User)e.Entity);
};
```

...

```
//ObjectMaterialized won't fire when you create the object
context.Person.Add(InitNewUser(new User()));
```

Your initialization code:

```
private static User InitNewUser(User user)
{
    //Your initialization code
    user.OtherProc();
    return user;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any example?...i'm new in ef.

Comment: It's possible extend the constructor method to diferent partial classes? Because I need execute the method when the class is instantiated, not when I load from database. Thank you. Pardon my ignorance.